# Why does Blazor GET request with negative integer parameter not work while running without debugging?

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly

I am building a Blazor WASM application which is getting data from my own API endpoint.
The url looks like this: /api/{controller}.

The endpoint allows filtering by Ids, which in some cases are negative integers.
When running the application with the debugger everything works as expected:

```
Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:7133/api/plannedworkhours?From=2021-02-01&To=2021-02-14&SpotId=-1
```

However, when running the code without debugging, the modelstate is invalid and the controller is throwing a bad request(which is intended when the modelstate is invalid) and the following log is presented:

```
Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:7133/api/plannedworkhours?From=2021-02-01&To=2021-02-14&SpotId=%E2%88%921
```

Seems like something is wrong with the url decoding, right?
It works as intended when not having a negative integers as parameters.

The request from the application looks like this:

```
            var url = $"/api/plannedworkhours?From={startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}&To={endTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}";
    
            if (spotIds != null && spotIds.Length > 0)
            {
                url += $"&{string.Join("&", spotIds.Select(sid => $"SpotId={sid}"))}";
            }

            return await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<PlannedWorkHourModel>>(url);
```

This is  the api encpoint:

```
            public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] PlannedWorkHoursQuery filter)
            {
                 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                 {
                     throw new BadRequestException(); //This exception is thrown when running without debugging, but not while debugging
                 }

            ....

            }
```

This is the query params:

```
public class PlannedWorkHoursQuery
{
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
    public short[] SpotId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you have to show plannedworkhours Api action too

Comment: Added that aswell

Answer (score 1):

since SpotId is an array, it should be looking like this in your query string

```
...&SpotId[0]=-1
```

Update

Since in the reality you have SpotId[0]=%E2%88%921 try to change SpotId to

```
public string[]? SpotId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Still the same...  Request finished HTTP/2 GET localhost:7133/api/plannedworkhours?From=2021-02-01&To=2021-02-14&SpotId[0]=%E2%88%921 - - - 400

Comment: @Tjulu SpotId[0]=%E2%88%921 is not SpotId[0]=-1 Why you don't show the real data and waisting my time?

Comment: Ehm, that is the request that is logged in the console, it is the real data.The only thing i altered is the removal of "https://" preceding the "localhost...." to prevent that its not formatted as a url in the comment here on stackoverflow. The "%E2%88..." is the core of the problem..

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it helped me further with the troubleshooting, it seems like the decoded version of %E2%88%921 is not -1 but −1. It's actually the longer version of the "-". That sounds like something that can cause issues with the parsing of the url parameters to me..

Comment: It works by doing this... id.ToString().Replace("−", "-"); before adding it to the query string from the blazor application. Quite ugly, but it works... :)

Comment: No part of Blazor would turn `-1` into `−1`, show us how you fill  spotIds in the client.

Comment: For sv-SE it would, I checked the System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign, its actually the invalid character in the CLDR. We swedes can't even type that letter with our keyboard layout (well, at least not easily..). https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44678 an issue from .net 5 which apparently still exists. To be clear, I am not altering any cultureinfo anywhere in the client application